# How to keep the original quick launch menu of a page even after replacing the page layout by another one?

Tags: page-layout

By code, when I create a new blank site and replace the welcome page layout by a new layout page, the original quick launch menu disapears. How to keep the original quick launch menu of a page even after replacing the page layout by another one?

Answer (score 1):

You must set the master page to one with the quick launch in the ContentPlaceHolder with the id PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" runat="server">
```

Visit MSDN to read more about [Creating Pages for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff354405%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hello, I need to get the result when I create a new site definition in Visual Studio. Not by SPD. Do you get the solution in this case ? Thanks

Comment: SharePoint Designer is not required, but a master page with the correct placeholders is. Often, master page development is started in SharePoint Designer, but you could do it all in Visual Studio if you preferred. You might want to start with copying the text of default.master from the SharePoint Root.

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for the time you give me. I red your comment but I must be too novice in this part of Sharepoint to understand what you mean. Would you be kind to take time again by explaining in details what to do exactly to get the result I wnant to ? It is really important to me to solve this problem cause I'm complety stuck in the project because of that. Thanks.